# How to pass an array of object to $stateParams value using angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a form something like this:

```
$scope.models = [{}, {}];

<div classs="" ng-repeat="each_model in models"> 
 <input class="" model="each_model.name"> Name
 <input class="" model="each_model.class"> Class
 <input class="" model="each_model.city"> City
</div>
```

Currently I am passing $scope.models to $stateParams, by passing complete data to parameters:

```
$state.go('class_report', {parameters: models});
```

==my app.js

```
        .state('class_report', {
            url: '/class_report?parameters',
            templateUrl: 'views/class_report.html',
        })
```

But passing data this way makes URL unreadable. So may question is, is there an way to pass this form data in such a way that it should be readable.
Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Why not use service to pass data between controllers

Answer (score 0):

> So may question is, is there an way to pass this form data in such a way that it should be readable

#### Short answer - No.

You can pass primitive values like strings, ints and booleans

However you can store this value in `module.service` under some unique key and pass this key in your URL. After that you can easily load it.

For example:

```
$scope.models = [{}, {}];
var uniqueKey = SomeService.setData($scope.models);
$state.go('class_report', {key: uniqueKey});
```

in other controller:

```
$scope.models = SomeService.getData($stateParams.key);
```

where `SomeService` code snippet is:

```
app.service('SomeService',function () {

   var self = this;
   self.models = {}; 

   self.setData = function(models){
     self.models[key] = models;
     return key;
   } 

    self.getData = function(key){
     return self.models[key]
   } 

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is to create a Service:

```
.factory('YourService',[function(){
    var models= {};
    return {
        set: function(data){
            models= data;
        },
        get: function(){
            return models;
        }
    }

}]);
```

And call it like this (after injecting it in the controller):
var models = `YouService.get()` To get the data

`YourService.set(data)` To set the data

Comment: I guess we wrote it in the same time, plus I described how the service should be implemented :)